# Are Wordpress Bin Folder's pages indexed by google search?

Tags: wordpress, google-search

I installed a new Theme on wordpress and I do not want to delete all pages because I probably will use them in future. At the same time I do not want google to index these pages so I thought to move them into the Bin folder.

Now my question is: 
Are Wordpress Bin Folder's pages indexed by google search?

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By bin folder, I'm guessing you mean the Wodpress trash bin? Once they're in the trash, they won't be indexed. Just be careful as Wordpress will automatically delete them after 30 days. Perhaps a better option is to save them as a draft since you plan to use them again in the future.

Comment: Thanks Boris that was the fix I needed. 